# Order strings case-insensitively in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, case-insensitive

How can I order `username` column values irrespective of case sensitive in MySQL RDBMS?

*Table structure and data :*

```
╔══════╦════════════╦════════╗
║  id  ║  username  ║  name  ║
╠══════╬════════════╬════════╣
║    1 ║   adam     ║  test  ║
║    2 ║   Ben      ║  test1 ║
║    3 ║   Aron     ║  test2 ║
║    4 ║   charles  ║  test3 ║
╚══════╩════════════╩════════╝
```

*Desired result :*

```
╔══════╦════════════╗
║  id  ║  username  ║
╠══════╬════════════╣
║    1 ║   adam     ║ 
║    2 ║   Aron     ║  
║    3 ║   Ben      ║  
║    4 ║   charles  ║ 
╚══════╩════════════╝
```

Comment: just do as `order by username` and it should work.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty It depends on the collation of the table.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I tried with order by username, but it didn't work.

Comment: Yes as @Barmar pointed out it depends on the Collation of the table, for `latin1_swedish_ci` this should work. But in case of other Collation it might fail. You can check your table Collation by running the following command `show table status where name ='your_table_name'`

Comment: Yes, i tried with ORDER BY CONVERT (username USING latin2) and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @saran non related question: How could you write tables used in this question. i.e what is the editor or the tool that you have used to make them rendered as shown in the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can format `username` to upper or lower case in the `order by` clause as follows:

```
order by lower(username)
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two  solutions for case insensitive.

- First is to use the `COLLATE` option :

  ```
   SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY username COLLATE `latin1_general_ci`;
  ```
- The MySQL query for case insensitive `ORDER BY` is to add the `LOWER()` to your field name :

  ```
   SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY LOWER(username);
  ```